# Accumulation and timing of heal

Tags: mage-knight

Is it possible to play `Refreshing Walk` (2 Move and 1 Heal) prior to a combat and then use the heal provided after the combat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refreshing Walk can only be played in the movement phase; the right to use the healing part of the effect expires before the combat phase (in which healing effects can't be played anyway).  By the time combat has finished, the window of opportunity to benefit from the healing qualities of the Refreshing Walk is long since over.

It would be quite bizarre to be able to save parts of an effect and have them happen in the distant future in general, I think (unless such a possibility was specifically allowed in writing).